# Why Gale Shapley matching algorithm third iteration is not executing?

Tags: python, algorithm, jupyter-notebook, graph-theory, bipartite

I am executing the following code of Gale Shapley matching algorithm in python, first two iteration are working fine but third iteration system stuck in loop. Kindly help to identify and resolve the issue

[image: Code output]

Libraries

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

Example preference lists for 3 men and 3 women

```
men_prefs = {
    'm1': ['w2', 'w1', 'w3'],
    'm2': ['w1', 'w2', 'w3'],
    'm3': ['w1', 'w3', 'w2']
}
women_prefs = {
    'w1': ['m3', 'm1', 'm2'],
    'w2': ['m2', 'm1', 'm3'],
    'w3': ['m1', 'm3', 'm2']
}
```

Create the bipartite graph

```
B = nx.Graph()
B.add_nodes_from(men_prefs.keys(), bipartite=0)
B.add_nodes_from(women_prefs.keys(), bipartite=1)
for man, prefs in men_prefs.items():
for woman in prefs:
B.add_edge(man, woman)
```

Run the Gale-Shapley algorithm

```
free_men = set(men_prefs.keys())
engaged = {}
while free_men:
    man = free_men.pop()
    woman = men_prefs[man][0]
    if woman in engaged:
        current_man = engaged[woman]
        if women_prefs[woman].index(man) < women_prefs[woman].index(current_man):
            engaged[woman] = man
            free_men.add(current_man)
        else:
            free_men.add(man)
    else:
        engaged[woman] = man
```

Draw the graph with the new matching

```
pos = nx.bipartite_layout(B, men_prefs.keys())
plt.figure(figsize=(6, 4))
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(B, pos, node_color=['lightblue'])
nx.draw_networkx_edges(B, pos, edgelist=engaged.items(), edge_color='red', width=2)
nx.draw_networkx_labels(B, pos, font_size=12, font_family='sans-serif')
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Your code always uses `woman = men_prefs[man][0]` and never updates `men_prefs`, so each M only ever tries to match with the same W.

Comment: Actually Gale Shapley matching algorithm is gender biased. It execute either on the preference of men or women not both.

Comment: Check the pseudocode here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gale%E2%80%93Shapley_algorithm. Focus on this part: "w := first woman on m's list **to whom m has not yet proposed**". Your code just takes the first woman on M's list and ignores "...first woman to whom M has not yet proposed".